# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, node.js

I get this error and ajax is not working on nodejs platform but it was working on Ruby on Rails. why is that?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        url: '/index0.html',
        beforeSend: function() {
          $('.ajax-container').show();
        },
        success: function(data) {

          $('.ajax-container').html(data);
          var name = sessionStorage.getItem('name');
          console.log(name);
          $('.registration-button').html("Welcome, " + name);
        },
        failure: function(request, status, error) {
          alert("Request failed. Please try again later.");
        },
        complete: function() {
          $('.spinner').delay(5000).fadeOut();
        }
      });
```

Comment: to get this error `async` parameret must be setted to `false`. Check your code, are you sure that problem is inside this call?

Comment: How is the code snippet related to the question?

Comment: @AndrewEvt 100% positive this is the code that triggers it as i get the name i want console.logged in the console. it just does not fetch the page.

Comment: @Teemu this error message happens when i trigger the ajax request.and it won't get the page i want.

Comment: Yes, but not that request in the snippet, as Andrew has already explained.

Comment: Not sure i get what you mean?